# Ajax.request throws a syntax error, but returns the correct value

Tags: javascript, ajax, syntax, prototypejs

I have a bunch of Ajax requests that execute just fine, but I end up with a syntax error in my browser.

Can anyone see what's wrong with my request below?

```
function getName(refId)
{
    var resp = '';
    new Ajax.Request('/servlet/GetName',
    {
        method:'post',
        parameters: {'requestType':'ref',
                 'value':refId},
        onSuccess:function(transport)
        {
            setName((String(transport.responseText)).trim());
        }
    });
}
```

edit: This also seems to only throw the error the first time it gets called.  If I clear the console, I don't continue to get errors.

Comment: syntax error
http://localhost:8080/servlet/<ServletName>
Line 1

Comment: Can you paste a block of your actual code instead of the stub? That may help in spotting the syntax error. I've faced similar situations earlier on, where FF would work fine but IE threw up syntax errors. 

More often that not, it was due to a misplaced / extra comma placed following the Ajax.Reqeuest()'s parameters.

Comment: I have edited the post to show the full function.  I have several that are slightly different, but all of them throw the syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gotten syntax errors using xmlhttprequest in Firefox to query non-xml as well. Firefox tries to parse the response as xml, and logs the error, but keeps working anyways.

In my case, I added this to the php on the server side:
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

Someone reported a client-side fix here:
[jQuery .getJSON Firefox 3 Syntax Error Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335409/jquery-getjson-firefox-3-syntax-error-undefined)

Comment: I finally got around to fixing this, and setting the content type in the header worked!  Thanks so much.

I added this line to my servlet: 

response.setContentType("text/plain");

Answer (score 0):

There is no root-property in the window object, according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_window.asp). Maybe if you use

```
new Ajax.Request(document.domain + '/servlet/GetName', ...
```

it will work better.

Edit, ah - I should learn to read. It does work, but throws a syntax error. Syntax errors != no implemented property... Sorry! But I will let my post stay anyway. ;)

Comment: As it turns out, window.root was returning nothing and it was implicitly adding the 'http://localhost:8080' to my request.  Changing it to document.domain changed the request url so that it didn't work anymore.  Hard-coding the url made no difference.