# not well-formed Source File in mozilla firefox

Tags: json, angularjs, firefox, content-type, http-get

Following is the content of my `JSON` File -

```
{
    "tags": [
        "Red",
        "Green",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ]
}
```

I checked this with [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) but still I am getting the following error in firefox.

> Timestamp: Wednesday 18 June 2014 10:39:41  IST Error: not well-formed
>   Source File:
>   file:///home/trialcode/trialcode/Projects/ang/18-06-2014/ang/content.json
>   Line: 1, Column: 1 Source Code: {

I am not sure what I am doing wrong if any.

FYI -

**OS** - Linux Ubuntu 12.04

**Firefox** - 24.0

**EDIT**

I am using the content of `content.json` file in angular controller via `$http.get` method.

I explored more about this kind of error and found it is related with the `Content-Type` setting.

Following is the full code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>JSON Read In Angularjs</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.data = {};
            $http.get('content.json').success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="em in data.tags">{{em}}</li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I set the content type if that is a problem. I searched [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#get) but unable to fix it. Help me Please if any.

Comment: Not sure what your actual problem is, but if you want to set the `Content-Type` HTTP header you can do so by providing a config parameter to `$http.get` (i.e. `$http.get('content.json', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})`.

Comment: @miqid I tried this but I am still getting "not well-formed" error in FF

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I had a brain fart - don't think it makes sense issuing a GET with `Content-Type` anyway. Another suggestion would be to check the server returning `content.json` is setting `application/json` as the MIME type. Or, if you're not using a server, I think this particular question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618959/not-well-formed-warning-when-loading-client-side-json-in-firefox-via-jquery-aj

Comment: @miqid I came across this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24281117/1594368

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few hours of searching I came across that -

> Chrome and other modern browsers have implemented security
>   restrictions for Cross Origin Requests, which means that you cannot
>   load anything through  file:/// , you need to use http:// protocol at
>   all times, even locally -due Same Origin policies.

Source -

1. [Cross Origin Script Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)
2. [Simple Solution For Local Cross Origin Requests](http://odiseo.net/front-end/simple-solution-for-local-cross-origin-requests)