# "not well-formed" called by handlebars.js while loading json into template from script

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I am trying to use handlebars.js to create and then inject html into a webpage. I'm testing it out using json written inside of the script before attempting to integrate the server. I have checked the json in a validator and it is all good, but I still get an error from the handlebars template claiming "not well-formed".

I read a few other people who were having issues with Cross Origin Requests, but I use Firefox which is the solution they suggest (Q: [not well-formed Source File in mozilla firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277695/not-well-formed-source-file-in-mozilla-firefox))

Could it be something with my handlebars file?

Here is my js code:

```
var html;
    var data= { "array":[
        {"firstname":"Joe","lastname":"Shmoe"},
        {"firstname":"John","lastname":"Connor"}
        ]};
    console.log(data);
    $.get("templates/coach-list-template.hbs",function(data){
        var template= Handlebars.compile(data);
        var handlebarshtml=template(data);
        console.log(handlebarshtml);
        console.log("Data: "+data);
    },"html");
```

And here is the handlebars code:

```
{{#each array}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-100"> {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the *template*, not the *data*. So, if you have this in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="mytemplate">
  {{#each array}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-100"> {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

You compile that template with

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('mytemplate').innerHTML);
```

and then apply the data by using that template:

```
var html = template(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` in your `$.get` context isn't the variable you defined in the outer scope.
The variable passed to the `$.get` callback is the result of the get request, for example:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

If you want to use both the request result and your data variable, rename one.

Answer (score 0):

see the answer here:
["not well-formed" warning when loading client-side JSON in Firefox via jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618959/not-well-formed-warning-when-loading-client-side-json-in-firefox-via-jquery-aj)

specifically, see the "beforeSend" option

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){
  if( xhr.overrideMimeType ){
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  }
}
```