# Malformed JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm getting a *malformed* JSON response from an AJAX $.getJSON() request. I don't understand the problem.

Here is the request code:

```
var myfunc = function(){
    $.getJSON( "/", {"data": ""}, function( data, status ){
        var values = data;

        $("#temperature").html( values.temperature.toFixed(1).toString() );
        $("#humidity").html( values.humidity.toFixed(0).toString() );
    });
});
```

and here is the JSON data received (extracted via Firefox debugger):

```
{
    "temperature": 17.799999237060547,
    "humidity": 35.900001525878906,
    "failed": false
}
```

I cannot see what is *malformed* here. And the code works. DOM elements `id="temperature"` and `id="humidity"` are updated correctly.

I got exactly the same result using `$.get()` with `JSON.parse()`.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: What is `malformed JSON` ? Everything looks good and it executes as expected then what is the concern ?

Comment: JSON seems alright to me. What is the issue exactly?

Comment: If temperature and humidity are updated correctly, then what is the issue?  Where are you getting "malformed JSON"?

Comment: Actually the only issue is that the Firefox debugger tells me that the JSON is malformed. THat is why I wrote "I don't understand" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the json data you are receiving over the network is malformed, but, it is successfully converted to an object anyway.

getJSON automatically applies JSON.parse(..) on the received data.

Try using the 'network' listener tab on Google Chrome to see exactly the response you are receiving BEFORE it is parsed. There might be a missing " or something like that.

If you have access to the server code, you could also try logging the response in there.

edit:
[you might be interested by this link](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/firefox-error-on-valid-local-json-load-not-well-formed)
Might have to do with some server config.
Mimetype is also mentionned [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618959/not-well-formed-warning-when-loading-client-side-json-in-firefox-via-jquery-aj).

Comment: Using Firefox network listener, I get correct JSON value.

Comment: I wrote the server code. The answer I send is "{\"temperature\": 10.0, \"humidity\": 20.0, \"failed\": false}", \" being literal " in C++...

Comment: Your second link allowed me to fix the bug. Thanks!