# jQuery.getJSON works in Safari, not Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This jQuery.getJSON works for me in Safari, but not FF or Chrome. In Safari, I get alerts with json name/value pairs. In FF/Chrome. I get the 3 error alerts (all returning empty strings). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<!-- language: javascript -->

$.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {   
    alert("text Status: " + textStatus);
    alert("error thrown: " + errorThrown);
    alert("response:" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
}});

$.getJSON("http://example.com/webservice",
  {
  },
  function(data) {
    for(var key in data){
             var attrName = key;
             var attrValue = data[key];
        alert('name='+ attrName + ' value=' +attrValue);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Have you run your JSON through [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to verify that it is valid?

Comment: Tip: You can use "example.com" when giving URL examples. It is reserved for this purpose.

Comment: Yes I've verified the json response with json lint. It passes

Comment: This page is also on `http://66.179.18.179:5000`, right?  You're not getting blocked by the Same Origin Policy?

Comment: I've putting this page up on that server, and I've tried testing locally. Same results.

Answer (score 0):

What MIME type is being returned? A similar looking problem was described here, with a workaround: [jQuery .getJSON Firefox 3 Syntax Error Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335409/jquery-getjson-firefox-3-syntax-error-undefined)

Comment: the service is returning content-type of text/html

Comment: @user738497: It should return a content-type of `application/json`

Comment: Content type is now set to application/json. No change in behavior

Comment: Try using FireBug in Firefox, and examine the actual response. Is it well formed JSON?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it with JsonLint repeatedly . It is valid JSON. Damned mysterious.

Comment: The problem seems to be that when I make the getJSON request, I'm getting back a status 0 error. The error handling above does not print out the error. However this does: `$.ajaxSetup({
  error:function(x,e){
   if(x.status==0){
   alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
   }`

Comment: Add this to your ajaxSetup:

beforeSend: function(xhr){jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){xhr.abort();});}

Found here: http://steveweintraut.blogspot.com/2009/12/firefoxsafari-ajax-status-code-0-bug.html